# MVC caching database images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I am creating a website with MVC 4. For project requirements, the images are stored in database. I have a View that I bind the Model in which I have the Id of the picture accompanying the story, then I get the image:

View:

```
<img src='<%= Url.Action("ShowImagen", "Home", new {id = item.IdImagen}) %>' style="width: 300px;
                        height: 200px;" />
```

Controller:

```
public FileResult ShowImagen(int id)
    {
        if (id > 0)
        {
            var imageData = new NoticiaRepository().GetImagen(id);
            return File(imageData, "image/jpg");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }           
    }
```

With this and checking it with Chrome, I've noticed that when I reload the page, It not load the images from the cache, like other files as .css or other images loaded from file system.

Is there any way to make these images are cached?
A greeting and thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could decorate your `ShowImagen` controller action with the [`[OutputCache]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, VaryByParam = "id")]
public ActionResult ShowImagen(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank's, I tried whith OutputCache, but not with the Location parameter.

Comment: @darin-dimitrov  And how can you invalidate the cache at some point? ( e.g. if the content of the one image changes )

Comment: Old post, but still helpful. Just for the record, for Dotnet Core, the attribute is now `ResponseCache`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried decorating your action method with [`OutputCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) attribute?

Comment: Than's Daniel, the key is OutputCache whit the parameter Location.